# CodeIginiter, not being able to do a JSON Encode output

Tags: json, parsing, codeigniter, decode, encode

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple, anyway, I have tried for the past three hours to JSON encode some query results, something I do it quite often with code igniter, however, it just doesn't work, and I have no idea why.

I'm using CodeIgniter (latest version), PHP5.

My three files.

material_model MODEL

```
public function get_types(){
    return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM material_types ORDER BY type_id")->result_array();
} // end function get_types

public function get_material($name){
    return $this->db->query("SELECT T.name as 'type', M.* FROM material M, material_types T WHERE T.type_id = M.type_id and T.name = '".$name."' ORDER BY M.type_id and M.order")->result_array();
} // end function get_material_all
```

material Controller

```
public function get_all(){
    $json['response'] = array('types' => array());
    $json['response']['types'] = $this->material_model->get_types();


    foreach ($json['response']['types'] as $item){
    $name = $item['name'];

    $json['response'][$name] = $this->material_model->get_material($name);          
    }

    $this->load->view('response', $json);
}
```

response VIEW

```
$this->output->set_status_header(200);
$this->output->set_header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

The results -> http://goethedev.com/iib_ci/index.php/material/get_all/

What I use to validate the JSON pages -> http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

I'm displaying the whole results up there, I already tried to narrow it down for testing purposes to just row_array, only a couple of fields from table material_types, but no luck, this is also a new server I'm working on, that's unlikely the problem, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Thanks.

Comment: How and where you are using the `json` encoded data ?

Comment: The data will be used in Appcelerator Titanium, however, after a lot of errors trying to parse it, I decided to use a JSON validator, http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/, and it gave me the result that the problem was on the server side, since the app is parsing JSON data alright from other sources.

Comment: In `Appcelerator Titanium` are you using `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: Yes, the code works fine pulling JSON encoded data from other sources, it's pretty straightforward, but if I try to do it from the url mentioned above, it doesn't return me anything.
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
var url = "http://goethedev.com/iib_ci/index.php/material/get_all/";
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
xhr.onload = function(e){Ti.API.info(JSON.parse(this.responseText));}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json being returned from the URL you provided is being displayed for me just fine, and it validates as well. Either you've fixed it since posting, or perhaps you need to clear your browser cache?

**UPDATE**

The code was validating just fine when I copy/pasted it to the validator you provided, but using the URL it fails. That tells me that there's something extra/wrong that's coming through  that isn't included when copy/pasting from the browser.

To identify it I ran `curl http://goethedev.com/iib_ci/index.php/material/get_all/ | less` and here's what I got:

```
<U+FEFF><U+FEFF><U+FEFF>{"types":[{"type_id":"0","name":"DISCLAIMER","timestamp":"2012-09-08 22:57:27"},
```

`<U+FEFF>` represents a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Since there are three of them, it appears three files in your CI project have the byte order mark included. I recommend, as does [PSR2](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md), always disabling the byte order mark in your PHP code. Your editor should have an option to remove/disable them. Once you do that, you should be able to parse the json.

Comment: It is displaying just fine, but using http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to validate it gives me the reply "JSON Data URL does not contain JSON data.", which is correct, since I can't seem to parse it elsewhere when I get the results.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried to validate through http://jsonlint.com/, and it gave me a JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '?', after some research, It gave me the byte order mark problem, gonna try to solve that right now, brb.

Comment: Thank you man, when I resaved the project files being explicit that it should be without BOM, it worked, I can't believe how many hours I've spent today in this, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `json` looks fine but you may also try this

```
public function get_all(){
    $response['types'] = $this->material_model->get_types();
    foreach ($response['types'] as $item){
        $response['name'][] = $this->material_model->get_material($item['name']);          
    }
    $this->load->view('response', array($response));
}
```

In the client side just try

```
xhr.onload = function(e){
    var jsonObject = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    if (jsonObject != null)
    {
        console.log(jsonObject); // see in the console if it prints anything
        Ti.API.info(...); // rest of your code
    }
}
```

[If this helps](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/139871/problem-jsonparsexhrresponsetext-in-android).

Comment: Thank you for the help Sheikh, but it was a case of Byte Order Mark, after I changed the files server-side, it finally worked!